# Countdown timer going off late

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, alarm

I've had a problem with the default clock app, specifically the countdown timer portion (also has alarm clock and regular timer in it). Sometimes it goes off late by several minutes when setting it for intervals under 1 hour. What could be causing this problem? I don't have any other apps which could affect time to my knowledge. Android version is 4.4.2, phone model is HTC 626G+.

Comment: Do you put this timer into the background by using other apps? I'm not sure Android gives the clock app any superceding precedence when shifted to the background. It'll receive (or not) priority to keep it alive or active. It may sleep, as is the habit of background processes. It would surprise me only if any alarms went off early.

Comment: I have a habit of swiping off any active apps so there's nothing in there, and the alarm, timer and everything else still works. So no, there aren't any other apps, and as I've said, I don't think I have any time related apps installed that could interfere. And the alarms have never went off early.